# swiper.scrollbar.updateSize() doesn't work in swiper.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, swiper.js

I'm using Swiper 6.8.1 to create a responsive carousel with a scrollbar. The code (in a separate swiper.js file that I inserted in my main HTML document) is as follows:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    observer: true,
    observeParents: true,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: 10,
    scrollbar: {
        el: ".swiper-scrollbar",
    },
    breakpoints: {
        576: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
            spaceBetween: 20,
        },
        768: {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetween: 30,
        },
        992: {
            slidesPerView: 4,
            spaceBetween: 40,
        },
    }
});
swiper.scrollbar.updateSize();
```

The Chrome console, however, displays the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateSize' of undefined`

Could I inquire as to what is producing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your are inserting `Swiper.JS` after your `custom-script`.

**Try this**, add Swiper.js first like

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/6.8.1/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

**And Then**

```js
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    observer: true,
    observeParents: true,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: 10,
    scrollbar: {
        el: ".swiper-scrollbar",
    },
    breakpoints: {
        576: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
            spaceBetween: 20,
        },
        768: {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetween: 30,
        },
        992: {
            slidesPerView: 4,
            spaceBetween: 40,
        },
    }
});

swiper.scrollbar.updateSize();
```

Let me know if this works!

Comment: I made the modifications, but the issue persists.